# resize an image to an exact size, retain aspect, and fill any space in php

Tags: php, image, resize, resize-image

hy,

Let's say I want to convert an image to an exact size, eg: 400x300. The trick is, if the image, due to its aspect ratio, does not fit in 400x300, then place it in there with black borders.

A 900x1200 image would be converted down to 225x300 to retain its aspect ratio, and then given black borders left and right to make it 400x300.

original photo:

```
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||  
|||||||||||||||||||||||
```

after resize i want to look something like this:

```
_______________________
|+++++++++++++++++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++|
|+++++++||||||||++++++|
|+++++++||||||||++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++|
|_____________________|
```

the: "+++++++" i want to be some color, and the "|||||||" are the image, in the middle!

unfortunately i don't have any code yet!

i want something like this:
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php#x22
thanks

Comment: show real photo example. I'm not getting what you are asking.

Comment: You haven't given a question (unless you want people to just write the code for you), so the most advice I can offer is to use a graphics library like ImageMagick or GD.

Comment: The aspect ratio calculations should seriously be of the least concern, it's simple math that you should be able to figure out pretty quickly. The bigger problem seems to be that you have no idea where to even start, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get familiar with the [`gd` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), which allow you to manipulate images.

You'll need to read in your image using one of the `imagecreatefrom...` functions. Then you'll need to create a second image using, for example, [`imagecreatetruecolor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), which you [fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) with your color of choice. Then you copy the original image into the new image using [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), which allows you to resize it in the process. You'll need to calculate the new size with some simple math beforehand, which functions like [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) can help  you with.

Alternatively, play around with the [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) class, which is an alternative to `gd` you may or may not find easier to work with.

Best of luck! :)

Comment: @robertdd There's lots of sample code for each function, the example for [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) is pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div styled to have a black background, and sized at 400x300. Then show your resized image inside that div. You can even include a check to make sure that the image is not the desired aspect before showing the div.

Something like this:

```
<? 
$height-ratio = $height / 300;
$width-ratio = $width / 400;

if ($height-ratio == $width-ratio) {
 $ratio = $height-ratio;
} elseif ($height-ratio > $width-ratio) {
 $ratio = $height-ratio;
 echo "<div class='blackbox'>";
} else {
 $ratio = $width-ratio;
 echo "<div class='blackbox'>";
}

$newHeight = $height / $ratio;
$newWidth = $width / $ratio;
echo "<img src='".$imgSrc."' height='".$newHeight."' width='".$newWidth."' />";

if ($height-ratio != $width-ratio)
 echo "</div>";
?>
```

With supporting css of:

```
.blackbox { 
 text-align: center;
 background-color: black;
 height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: i need to save the photo, not only to display it

Comment: Good thinking. No need to waste bandwidth on a solid bg--especially if the image is going to be output in compressed JPEG format, which makes solid colors look terrible. If you need to save it, then I would stick with PNG or SVG (SVG is less supported, but will render the background most efficiently).

Comment: You may not be wasting bandwidth on a solid background, but you're still downloading a potentially massive image, which just gets scaled down to 400x300 by the browser. Which is likely wasting a lot more bandwidth than a bit of black border.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a big fan of editing and resizing the pictures in advance to be the size I want rather than setting the width and height when it is rendered.  The performance is better and you don't have to worry about how different browsers might handle it differently.

So if you don’t have an image editing program get Paint.net.  Free and works well.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I am saying. I'm saying on your PC re-size the image, then when you web page is rendered the browser doesn't have to do the work of re-sizing it.